# Error message when trying to install libxml2-dev on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, libxml2

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04

Ran `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` in terminal. However it returned the messages below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.10+dfsg-6.3ubuntu0.1) but 2.9.12+dfsg-0+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What does  `libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.10+dfsg-6.3ubuntu0.1) but 2.9.12+dfsg-0+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed` mean? How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation: `libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.7) but 2.9.4-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+2 is to be installed`

I somehow had a newer version, than the package depended on. I solved this with a downgrade: `apt-cache policy libxml2` --> `apt install libxml2=2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.7`

Answer (score 1):

Solution here (but I wrote the tutorial in French) : https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22551079

Long story short : Uninstall ppa:ondrej/php via ppa-purge solved my issue !

command to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Keep in mind the consequences of removing famous [Ondrej PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/). Maybe you added for a reason related to older versions of PHP.

Comment: Think thrice before running this. opndrej/php is _very_ useful if you're working with PHP. Allows you to easily fetch various PHP versions, and needed extensions.